# Use of onTouchEvent in GestureDetector

Tags: android, gesturedetector

I am quite new to android. I was learning the use of GestureDetector and wasnt able to understand the use of the following snippet in the code-

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {  
  if (mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event))  
    return true;  
  else  
    return false;  
}
```

Please tell me the relevance of the above code.
The snippet is from this website-
https://web.archive.org/web/20210127131521/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/06/implement-gesturedetector-in-android.html

Comment: onTouchEvent() is for handling touch screen motion events.You should implement onTouchEvent() if you are implementing the GestureDetector.OnGestureListener. onTouchEvent will get called when the touch motionevent occurs. If you only want to listen for a subset, extend GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple, we use this to pass the MotionEvent for performing the other functions. As all the functions in GestureDetector are performed on the touch.